# Automate the Rails server gem dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Consider the following example Rails server's (Server A) dependecies -

- gem A - 1.2.0.SNAPSHOT
- gem B - 2.4.0.SNAPSHOT
- gem C - 3.5.1.SNAPSHOT

Now, gem A and gem B has a dependency on gem D.

- gem A and gem B has this in its gemspec - gem 'gemD', '~> 2.3.0.SNAPSHOT'

Each gem is managed by a different team.

now, the team which manages gemD releases the 2.3.0 version and updates the snapshot version of gemD to 2.4.0.SNAPSHOT.

the team which manages Gem A, then goes and updates gem A's dependency so that it pulls in the latest version of gem D. However, the team which manages Gem B does not update its dependency.
So the gem dependencies now are -

- gem A's gemspec - gem 'gemD', '~> 2.4.0.SNAPSHOT'
- gem B's gemspec - gem 'gemD', '~> 2.3.0.SNAPSHOT'

Now when we do a 'bundle install' on server A, it fails and throws an error saying that gem A needs a 2.4.0.SNAPSHOT version of gem D while gem B needs a 2.3.0.SNAPSHOT of gem D.

So then we would need to ask gem B's owners to update its dependency and then only the bundle install would succeed on server A.

I was wondering if there is an automated way to resolve a server' gem dependency.

Comment: Aren't you using bundler to install gems? 

Comment: The automated way of managing library dependencies **is RubyGems**. That is its **entire purpose**.  The situation you describe should not be a problem, all that will happen is you will not be able to upgrade *any* Gem until the new set of dependencies is consistent. There should be no error output. If you're using semantic versioning for your projects, and your Gems list their dependencies correctly, this should never be a problem.